# Run Cron PHP script Every Minute Except 5 Minutes Out Of Day

Tags: php, sql, cron

Right now I have my cron running a php script every minute of every day. But I am looking to have it skip 5 minutes out of the day to allocate to downtime to truncate the sql table associated with it and perform other routine maintenance.

How might I go about this?

Comment: Why can't you add the logic to the PHP script? If it starts within those five minutes, simply do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This skips the last 5 minutes of the last hour of the day. The first entry runs every minute for the first 23 hours of each day. The second entry runs only on the first 55 minutes of the 24th hour of the day.

```
*     0-22     *     *     *     <command>
0-54  23       *     *     *     <command>
```